# <asp:button> is not working in IE9

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, button

I have a asp button in my application, which is working fine in mozilla, chrome, and IE 8 but it is not working in IE 9, I tried a lot but not getting any solution.

Someone please help me in this

```
<asp:Button CssClass="Button" ID="btnInsert" runat="server" Text="Insert" OnClick="btnInsert_Click" />
```

When I am checking my button with developer tools (F12) my button is showing like this

```
<input name="btnInsert" class="Button" id="btnInsert" type="submit" value="Insert"/>
```

My button Click code

When I am trying to debug it after Button Click then pointer is going to this click but page is not submitting, but that it working fine in other browser..

```
protected void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Id > 0)
    {
        this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), string.Format("Page1{0}", this.UniqueID), string.Format("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>Insert('{0}');</script>", Id));
    }
    else
    {
        lErrorMessage.Visible = true;
    }
}
```

JavaScript which i am calling on button click

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">   
    function Insert(Id)
    {
        if (window.opener.InsertText != null)
        {
            window.opener.InsertText(Id)
            window.close();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally I got the answer,

there were some javascript problem on some other page which I was calling at the time of opening InsertText page.

thanks a lot for all of you for your comments and answers.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you don't have any other dom element anywhere on your page that uses the id `btnInsert`.  More often than not problems like this are caused my duplicate IDs.

Trying changing the ID of this buttons to something crazy, like `ZZZZXXXXAAA` and see if your page starts working

---

As @Grrbrr404 mentions, also inspect your page for malformed html *before* your button.

Comment: Make also sure that there is not any other malformed HTML before your button. Something like a missing ", > or <

Comment: I tried with changing the name and ID, HTML also is well formed but its not working :(

Comment: Is the resulting HTML page the same in IE9 as in the other browsers? (View the source.) Or can you post the resulting HTML somewhere, so we can check?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. For me, the problem was that there was two form tags inside the page. One with runat=server and another one inside that tag without runat=server.